# How to manage operator overloading with inheritance

Tags: c++

I've got a matrix class with several overloaded operator but I need to extended it. I've got some compilation error. A toy program to show the problem:

```
template<typename T, int R, int C>
class matrix {
public:
  matrix() {};
  matrix(const matrix<T,R,C>& rhs) {}
  matrix<T,R,C> operator+(const matrix<T,R,C>& rhs) {
                 matrix<T,R,C> result(); /*some code*/ return result;
  }
  ~matrix() {}
  matrix<T,R,C>& operator=(const matrix<T,R,C>& rhs) {
        return *this;
  }
};

class point: public matrix<double, 1, 2> {
public:
  point();
};

int main() {
  point p1;
  point p2, p3;
  p1 + p2 <---------error

  p1 = p2 + p3; <-------error
  return 0;
}
```

Compiler error is:

```
In instantiation of ‘matrix<T, R, C> matrix<T, R, C>::operator+(const matrix<T, R, C>&) [with T = double; int R = 1; int C = 2]’:
a.cpp:28:13:   required from here
a.cpp:7:93: error: could not convert ‘result<double, 1, 2>’ from ‘matrix<double, 1, 2> (*)()’ to ‘matrix<double, 1, 2>’
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vexing parse again.

```
matrix<T,R,C> result();
```

declares a function named `result` taking no parameters and returning a `matrix<T,R,C>`. Take out the parens.

---

> When I try to extend the class I want to return from `operator+()` and so on object of the child class.

Then you need to give the derived class its own operators. How is a base class function supposed to know that it is actually operating on a derived class?